# Assign class to a dynamically created input field JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a jQuery plug-in (http://www.texotela.co.uk) for checking input which doesn't allow input to be character.
When I use it on my static HTML input it works fine, but when I use it on my dynamically created input using JavaScript, it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "js/sizeTopping.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="priceE" class="numeric" placeholder="Price"/>
<div id="add"></div>

<script src = "validator.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.each(restaurantSizes, function(i, field){
    outC += "<input type='text' class='numeric' name='price' "+
            "id='p"+ field.id +"' placeholder='Price' value='" + 0 + "'/></br>";
});
document.getElementById('add').innerHTML = outC;
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: `Initialize` the `plug-in` for newly created element..

Comment: What is `restaurantSizes`? Also when you are using jQuery, why dont you just use `$().html()`

Comment: @RayonDabre how to initialize that? actually using class='numeric' works in html

Comment: `Validator.js` find the elements having class as `numeric` on page load but it not aware of the elements added later..

Comment: @RayonDabre is there any way to use it on elements added later?

Comment: Read the documentation of the `validator.js`..They will have method to do so..